# Reverting back pvresize command for a partition on a single disk

Tags: linux, lvm

While I was trying to extend my lvm for the / filesystem I made a mistake. And I am not sure if it is a mistake as well.
Instead of creating new partition and adding it to pv,vg, and expanding the lv afterwards, I started with the command "pvresize" for the current partition which is being served for the root file system.

The command that i executed was:

```
[root@...]pvresize /dev/sda3 --setphysicalvolumesize 40G
```

Then I tried to extend the vg with the following:

```
 [root@...]# vgextend titan /dev/sda3 
  /dev/sdc: open failed: No medium found
  WARNING: Device /dev/sda3 has size of 58351616 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 83884032 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vg have changed sizes.
  Physical volume '/dev/sda3' is already in volume group 'vg'
  Unable to add physical volume '/dev/sda3' to volume group 'vg'
  /dev/sda3: physical volume not initialized.
```

Just after seeing the output above I realized that I had to create another partition on the single disk that I am operating on and add it to the pv group, extend the volume group then grow my logical volume for the root file system.

Question: How can I safely revert back the physical volume size to the point where I started in order to make this WARNING about size change disappear?

Here you can find the info that I think you would need for further guidance to the solution:

```
[root@...]# lsblk -b
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM          SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0  480103981056  0 disk 
├─sda1           8:1    0     629145600  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2           8:2    0    1073741824  0 part /boot
└─sda3           8:3    0   29876027392  0 part 
  ├─lv-root 253:0    0   21474836480  0 lvm  /
  └─lv-swap 253:1    0    8396996608  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

```
[root@t...]# pvdisplay -m -v
    WARNING: Device /dev/sda3 has size of 58351616 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 83884032 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG titan have changed sizes.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               <40.00 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              10239
  Free PE               3117
  Allocated PE          7122
  PV UUID               FgC2QI-pRpK-LZNS-di9w-Jc1d-XGXZ-2QxZI2

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 5119:
    Logical volume  /dev/lv/root
    Logical extents 0 to 5119
  Physical extent 5120 to 7121:
    Logical volume  /dev/lv/swap
    Logical extents 0 to 2001
  Physical extent 7122 to 10238:
    FREE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time on internet and having no clue about what I am going to do, i just noticed the error itself and taught that I can use the exact sector size mentioned over there. So I executed the command:

```
[root@...] pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 58351616s
```

And it worked flawless.

```
[root@t...]# pvdisplay
   --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               27.82 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7122
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          7122
  PV UUID               FgC2QI-pRpK-LZNS-di9w-Jc1d-XGXZ-2QxZI2

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda4
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               20.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5119
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          5119
  PV UUID               n5CdvZ-0s9A-iZoz-A2i7-icF9-Wv42-CsL3s9
```